# Select Maximum Values From Dataframe According to Date and ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My input dataframe;

```
ID  Date         Value
42  2018-01-01   10
42  2018-01-02   11
42  2018-01-04   13
42  2018-01-09   17
42  2018-05-04   5
42  2018-05-08   6
42  2018-06-10   2
43  2018-02-10   20
43  2018-02-11   21
43  2018-02-13   23
43  2018-02-17   10
```

Dataframe is ordered by ID and Date.

I want to get the value just before the first row where the values in the "Value" column is decreasing.

Desired output is;

```
ID  Default1    Default2    Default3
42  17          6           2
43  23          10          -
```

I couldn't really figure it out. Could you please help me about this?

Comment: default1 is max value, default3 is min value, what is default2?

Comment: Nope, dataframe is ordered by first id, second date. For the ID 42, Value 17 is followed by a value of 5. So it's decreasing, the default 1 is 17. Same as for Value 6, after value is 2, so it's decreasing and default 2 is 6. Default 3 is 2 because there are no values after all and dataframe continues with the other ID.